# JasperReport API: createReport returns null because of html component

Tags: java, parameters, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with *JasperReports API*.

I add *html* component into my report (via *iReport designer 5.0.4*). Compilation to *jasper* file runs without errors.

When I try create the report I get ***null*** from *JasperPrint object* (method *`createReport(getReportAsByteArray(), parameters, dataSource);`* returns ***null*** instead of *JasperPrint* object.

*`getReportAsByteArray()`* - returns jasper report file from my database).

The *Html* component (in *iReport*) is connected with string parameter, I put right string parameter into `parameters` HashMap<>. I already have tried write html text in html content exp. (html component properties).
It didn't work.

Earlier everything was fine, when the jasper file was without *html* component I could create my report and export to PDF.

Now I can see the resulting report (with *html* component) in my *iReport* preview (and it works), but when I fill my report via my java bean - it doesn't work.
(the jasper file with only one object - *html* component - didn't work too).

jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="raport_test_1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5a918503-735f-4812-bbd1-f4017cca4b0f">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="TEXT_CONTENT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="e9907391-3e2f-45c9-af15-b7a60f7a3312" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="125"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RealSize" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA[$P{TEXT_CONTENT}]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And the method, which should return byte array of report pdf file

```
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("TEXT_CONTENT","sample text<br/>");
    List<Data> list= getList();
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);

    JasperPrint printableReport = createReport(getReportFileAsByteArray(), parameters, dataSource);

    if (printableReport != null) {
        try {
            return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(printableReport);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            //
        }
    }
    return null;
```

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: You should post the code and the *jrxml* sample

Comment: I added the java code and jrxml file.